# Setting up a hash with an array value

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I am looking to set up a hash with an array as the value i.e.,

```
customers = {first: [name, age, height, etc], second: [name, age, height, etc], ...}
```

How can I access and edit the customers specific attributes such as `customers[first[age]]`?

Comment: give `customers[:first][1]` a try (assumes age is always the second element).

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using an array as the value to the hash? Also why use a hash to store the customers? A better way would be to use an array to store the customers and a ruby object as the elements in the array. That depends on your use case though.

Comment: Are the elements of your arrays (`name`, `age`, etc.) intended to be variables or methods? If they are meant to be literals you need to make them strings (`"name"`) or symbols (`:name`).

Comment: If you want to have both, field access by name and being an array, you could have a look at the gem [arrayclass](https://rubygems.org/gems/arrayclass/versions/0.1.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your individual customers data is an Array like you showed then you need it to have fixed indexes for those attributes, like name always at index 0, age at index 1 and you can access the data by doing

```
customers[:first][0] # name
customers[:first][1] # age
customers[:first][2] # height
```

but if you control how the data is being generated then you should use [Ruby Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html) for this purpose so the generated data should be in this format, an array of hashes

```
customers =  [{ name: 'John Doe', age: 30, height: 175 }, { name: 'John Doe', age: 30, height: 175 }]
```

and you can now do

```
customers.first[:name] # for first customer
customers[0][:age] # for first customer

customers[1][:name] # for second customer
```

Comment: thank you for this, how could i think check the entire hash to see if a customers name is already present? i.e. how to loop through only the names in each hash.

Comment: how is your customers hash structured now, is it like `customers = {first: [name, age, height, etc]}` or `customers = [{ name: 'John Doe', age: 30, height: 175 }]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for a different way to set up this data structure, here's another option:

Set up a class `Customer`

```
class Customer
   attr_accessor :name, :age, :height
   def initialize(name:, age:, height:)
     @name = name
     @age = age
     @height = height
   end
end
```

Then however you set up your collection, either an array or a hash, you can access the elements attributes by calling a method on the object.

Here's an array example:

```
customers = [
  Customer.new(name: "John", age: 30, height: 175),
  Customer.new(name: "Sam", age: 25, height: 160)
]
```

Then you could access the elements as

```
customer[0].name
# => "John"
customer[0].name = "Tom"
# => "Tom"
customer[1].age
# => 25
# etc...
```